# jQuery, Chrome and "selected" attribute anomalies

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've come across an issue in Chrome and I can't tell if it's a bug with Chrome, a bug with jQuery, or an error in my code.  I've search through open issues with Chromium and couldn't find anything and likewise with jQuery. I've created a JSFiddle here (and will include the code below for posterity):
http://jsfiddle.net/trmackenzie/cvPhd/4/

Expected:
When I click on a radio button, the indicated values are selected in the options list.  Also, if I click a specific option in the list, all radio buttons are deselected.

Actual (in Chrome 21 for Windows and Mac):
Only the last desired option is selected when clicking a radio button for the first time and then subsequent clicks causes nothing to happen.  If a specific option in the list is chosen, a radio button remains selected.

Actual (in IE7,8,9 and Firefox):
Same as expected behavior, e.g. correct behavior.

Note that the "selected" attribute on the option(s) is being set correctly but Chrome stops displaying its state.

Here is the code that is also available in jsFiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>Testing</title></head>
<body>
    <select size="10" name="testList" multiple="multiple" id="testList_box" style="width:250px; float:left; margin-right:20px;">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
        <option value="5">Fifth</option>
    </select>
    <span id="columnSpecList">
        <input type="radio" id="input1" name="spec" value="1" />
            <label for="input1">Testing</label>
        <input type="radio" id="input2" name="spec" value="1,2" />
            <label for="input2">Testing</label>
        <input type="radio" id="input3" name="spec" value="1,2,3" />
            <label for="input3">Testing</label>
    </span>
</body>
</html>​
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var columnList = $('#testList_box');
var columnSpecList = $('#columnSpecList');
var columnSpecOptions = $('input', columnSpecList);

    $(columnSpecOptions).click(function () {
        var optionsToSelect = $(this).val().split(',');

        // clear the list
        $(':selected', columnList).removeProp('selected');

        // select desired columns
        $(optionsToSelect).each(function (index, value) {
            $('[value=' + value + ']', columnList).prop('selected', 'true');
        });
    });

    $(columnList).on(
        {
            click: deselectSpec,
            change: deselectSpec
        }
    );

    // simulate "click" of the selected option to load the initial values
    var itemToClick = $(":checked", columnSpecList);
    $(itemToClick).click();

    function deselectSpec() {
        $(columnSpecOptions).removeProp('checked');
    }
});​
```

Have I come across a bug or (more likely) am I missing some subtlety in my implementation somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

don't use .removeProp()!! unless you plan on never using the property again.  Use boolean values to set them ex

```
.prop('checked',true or false)
```

From jQuery docs [.removeProp](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

You had

```
// clear the list
$(':selected', columnList).removeProp('selected');

 // select desired columns
 $(optionsToSelect).each(function (index, value) {
       $('[value=' + value + ']', columnList).prop('selected', 'true');
 });
```

Change it to

```
$(':selected', columnList).prop('selected',false);

 // select desired columns
 $(optionsToSelect).each(function (index, value) {
      $('[value=' + value + ']', columnList).prop('selected', true);
  });
```

and you had

```
function deselectSpec() {
    $(columnSpecOptions).removeProp('checked');
}
```

Change it to

```
function deselectSpec() {
     $(columnSpecOptions).prop('checked',false);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cvPhd/7/

Comment: Sigh...clearly I've once again fallen prey to the distinctions between attributes and properties (and when to remove them and when not to).  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  I've switched over not too long ago.. It actually makes more sense :)

Comment: Am I going mad, or didn't used to have to use removeProp? Was there a change in jQuery?

Comment: Since jQuery 1.6 they introduced .prop() and it is the preferred method to use to set/get property values like select/checked... `.prop(property,true/false)` is the correct way to set the property values.  `.removeProp()` will remove the property from element and you will not be able to use that property anymore..  I believe you are talking about `.removeAttr()`?

Comment: yeah maybe, have an upboat anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I used attr() and removeAttr() method instead of removeProp() and prop() and everything works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var columnList = $('#testList_box');
        var columnSpecList = $('#columnSpecList');
        var columnSpecOptions = $('input', columnSpecList);

        $(columnSpecOptions).click(function () {
            var optionsToSelect = $(this).val().split(',');

            // clear the list
            $(columnList).find('option').removeAttr('selected');

            // select desired columns
            $(optionsToSelect).each(function (index, value) {
                $('[value=' + value + ']', columnList).attr('selected', 'selected');
            });
        });

        $(columnList).on(
            {
                click: deselectSpec,
                change: deselectSpec
            }
        );

        // simulate "click" of the selected option to load the initial values
        var itemToClick = $(":checked", columnSpecList);
        $(itemToClick).click();

        function deselectSpec() {
            $(columnSpecOptions).removeProp('checked');
        }
    });​
```

Edit: Fixed code

Comment: When dealing with "selected" state I know you want to deal with the property rather than an attribute.  jQuery is somewhat forgiving on that (it handles making the appropriate change) but it's faster and more appropriate to modify the property.  See John Resig's older explanation at http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/.  But, per wirey's point, I should not be removing the property and should instead be setting it to false.