# Chrome not refreshing multi select element

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a very simple element in my HTML of:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="19" name="Title[book_types_array][]" id="Title_book_types_array">
    <option value="0">None Selected</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Textbook School</option>
    <option value="2">Textbook Undergraduate</option>
</select>
```

And I have a bit of JQuery which magically allows for single click mutliple selections:

```
$('select[multiple] option').click(function(e){
   var self = $(this);
   e.preventDefault();
   if (self.attr('selected'))
       self.removeAttr('selected');
   else
       self.attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

And this works just dandy on Firefox but not Chrome.

It technically works on Chrome but it does not refresh the element. As an example I select two options and then de-select them, it still shows them as selected. However, when I select a new option in the element it will now refresh and de-select the two elements correctly that I un-selected earlier. It will also refresh the element if I click on another window and then back again.

Is this some kind of bug in Chrome with this element or is there something I am missing?

#### Edit

By looking in console I can see how it is taking off the selected attribute, it just is not refreshing the element.

Added example: http://jsfiddle.net/Udf5c/

Comment: If only update/refresh when you click outside... you can emulate it adding `$('select[multiple]').blur().focus();` at the end of the function as a workaround ;-) this will update the list for you. [See Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Udf5c/1/)

Now, if you can use the **.prop** solution as @scx suggested, I also would recommend that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some research for that subject as your problem was very interesting. It seems that its better to use prop() instead of attr(). http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/

Also this post maybe some of use for you : [jQuery, Chrome and "selected" attribute anomalies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203767/jquery-chrome-and-selected-attribute-anomalies)

```
    $('select[multiple] option').mousedown(function(e){
   var self = $(this);
   e.preventDefault();
console.log(self.attr('selected'));

   if ( self.is(':selected'))
        self.prop('selected', false);
   else
        self.prop('selected', 'selected');

});
```

Here is working example that i've tried under chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/7sZUj/
Hope that will help you.

Comment: Aye that does work on chrome, broken on ff now though, but I will work on it see if I can get it working, thanks!

Comment: @ToddSprang Indeed, though fortunately due to this being internal I don't need to care about IE :) just threw that browser in the bin

Comment: You are right, FF not working at all now. Have you ever tried select2 or chosen libaries? I recomend checking it maybe that will let you avoid this problems http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: @scx Yea I might need to go down this route too :( was hoping for an easy fix there but it seems to get it working on both is a real hassle, your answer is right so I will tick yours, hopefully browser will become more standard with this in time and we can use it

Answer (score 0):

OK, since IE is off the table, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Udf5c/5/

```
$('select[multiple] option').mousedown(function(e){

    var sel = $(this).parent('select');
    var opt = $(this);

    var pushTarget = false;

    var selectedOptions = sel.find('option:selected');

    if (opt.attr('selected')) {
        selectedOptions = 
            $($.grep(selectedOptions, function(val) {
                return $(val).val() != opt.val();
            }));

    } else {
        selectedOptions.push(opt);
    }

    sel.children().each(function() {
        $(this).attr('selected', false); 
    });

    selectedOptions.each(function() {
        var o = sel.find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
        o.attr('selected', 'selected');
    });

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

It checks what's just been selected, then unselects everything and reselects the ones you want. :)

Comment: If I remove e.preventDefault it doesn't work at all for me and only allows the default click, not what the script actually does

Comment: Ah, I mistook single-click select for click-and-drag to select.

Comment: Wow this is weird: I just tried your original code, and it actually works fine, except there's a lag anywhere between .5 to 3 or 4 seconds until the element gets highlighted.

Comment: Hmm weird, I am on windows 7 and I find it works if I move the mouse outside the element

Comment: Not even lag. Click 1st item, seems to work fine. Click 2nd item, seems not to highlight at all, but move the mouse out of the SELECT, and it redraws correctly. Feels like a bug in Chrome. - Missed your response by seconds. Agree with your findings.

Comment: Indeed it does feel that way :(